# Using Z3 with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, z3, .net-core

Can the Microsoft Z3 .NET API handle .NET Core? We're using it in a scheduling algorithm for a school project, and we believe when the project was upgraded to .net core, z3 stopped working. We can't find any information on z3 being used with .net core.

Answer (score 1):

Z3 uses code contracts, which are not available in .NET core. However, we have a dummy class that replaces them, and which comes with the source code, see [src/api/dotnet/core/DummyContracts.cs](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/dotnet/core/DummyContracts.cs).

At the moment, this is not tied into the rest of our build infrastructure, but you can build them thusly:

```
cd src/api/dotnet/core
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

(Make sure you update your copy of the source code as I just committed a fix for the Core build.)

Comment: Do you know of any reason we'd be getting this error?
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libz3.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.Z3.Native.LIB.Z3_del_context(IntPtr a0)
   at Microsoft.Z3.Context.Finalize()

Comment: Z3 is native code, implemented in libz3.dll and it has a .NET API implemented in C#, and you need both to run programs that use Z3. Microsoft.Z3.dll will then try and find libz3.dll at the first call to a Z3 function. You error message means that libz3.dll could not be found; on Windows, it needs to be in the PATH and while you're building things it will usually reside in the "build" directory.

Answer (score 1):

For Z3 to work in a .Net Core 2 project you need the following things:

1. The Microsoft.Z3.dll in your project and add a reference to it in the project. Place it in the project root if unsure.
2. The libz3.dll as well but this doesn't need to be referenced (won't work anyways).
3. Add the libz3.dll and z3.exe to your PATH, either through code or by your OS. (this part is the one often resulting in dll not found errors).

** My code in C#

```
// Convinient metod to decide OS. false => linux in this case.
public static bool IsWindows() =>
    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);

private static void AddZ3ToProcessPath()
{
    // We store our OS-dependent Z3 DLLs in diffrent folders in our root.
    var solverZ3Path = IsWindows() ? "z3winx64_485" : "z3linuxx64_485";

    var z3X64BinariesPath = "";

    if (IsWindows())
    {
        z3X64BinariesPath = $"{solverZ3Path}"; // Windows friendly
    }
    else
    {
        z3X64BinariesPath =$"/{solverZ3Path}"; // Unix friendly
    }


    var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(z3X64BinariesPath); // Escape chars
    var name = "PATH"; // Add dlls to this environment variable
    var target = EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process; // But only for this process and not entire machine or user
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(name, path, target);
}
```

What OS are you using, what version of .Net Core? Any link to code?